# How to convert table to longtable being able to break across pages?

Tags: tables, longtable

As per question title, how can I convert the following table to longtable with the same result (but being able to break across pages)?

```
\begin{center}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{ | p{1.9cm} | p{9.9cm} | p{1.7cm} |  }
    \hline
    {\bf First} & {\bf Second} & {\bf Third} \\ \hline

    Text   & Other Text    & Other Text 2 \\ 
           & Other Text 3  &              \\ 
           & Other Text 4  &              \\ \hline

    Text 5 & Other Text 6  & Other Text 7 \\ 
           & Other Text 8  &              \\ 
           & Other Text 9  &              \\ \hline    
    \end{tabular}

\caption{My Table}
  \label{myTable}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

There are many more lines in my table.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Add `\usepackage{longtable}` to the preamble, remove `table` environment and change `tabular` to `longtable`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,vmargin=6cm,hmargin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{|*3{p{2cm}|}}
    \hline
    {\bf First} & {\bf Second} & {\bf Third} \\ \hline

    Text   & Other Text    & Other Text 2 \\ 
           & Other Text 3  &              \\ 
           & Other Text 4  &              \\ \hline

    Text 5 & Other Text 6  & Other Text 7 \\ 
           & Other Text 8  &              \\ 
           & Other Text 9  &              \\ \hline    
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Adding caption and label is also supported, it is very easy. Read the details [Sample Long Table](http://users.sdsc.edu/~ssmallen/latex/longtable.html).

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I had to move the caption to the beginning and the label as well.

Comment: @Weslei: Visit the given link, adding caption and label is easy. :-) The given example is self-explanatory.