# Table positioning won't do what I want

Tags: tables, positioning, report

I want to write a report Portfolio (Berichtsheft in german) with LaTeX. There has to be a table where I can write in what I did everyday, split up in work hours. And under that two fields where we can sign the pages.

This is what I do have until now:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{ngerman} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{eso-pic} 
%\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}



%\tymin=2cm
%\tymax=15cm


\newcommand{\foot}[5]{% 
\AddToShipoutPicture*{ 
  \setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}  
  \put(21,34){
    \begin{tabularx}{183mm}{|p{0.1\textwidth}|c|c|c|}\hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\footnotesize \textbf{Auszubildender}} 
      & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\footnotesize \textbf{Ausbildender bzw. Ausbilder}} \\[1cm] 
     \multicolumn{1}{|l}{................} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{........................................................} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{|l}{................} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{........................................................} \\[-2mm] 
     \multicolumn{1}{|l}{\footnotesize Datum} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\footnotesize Unterschrift} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{|l}{\footnotesize Datum} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\footnotesize Unterschrift} \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
  }
} 
} 



\newcommand{\head}[4]{%
    \begin{center}%
      \begin{tabular}{rl} 
       \textbf{Ausbildungsjahr:} & #1 \\ 
       \textbf{Ausbildungsnachweis Nr.:} & #2 \\ 
       \textbf{für die Woche:} & \textbf{vom} #3 \textbf{bis} #4 \\ 
       %\textbf{Betrieblicher Funktionsbereich:} & #5 \\ 
      \end{tabular} 
    \end{center} $ $ \\[8mm]
} 

\fancyhead[L]{ 
      \begin{tabular}{ll} 
        \large \textbf{Name des Auszubildenden:} & MAX MUSTERMANN \\ 
        \large \textbf{Ausbildungsbetrieb:} & MUSTERMANN AG \\ 
      \end{tabular} 
} 

\fancyhead[CR]{} 
\fancyfoot[LCR]{} 

\pagestyle{fancy} 

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{titlepage} 
  \begin{center} 
    \Huge{\underline{\textbf{Ausbildungsnachweis}}} 
  \vspace{5cm}
\end{center}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \textbf{Name}   &   :   & \textbf{MAX MUSTERMANN} \vspace{0.5cm} \\ 
      geboren am    &   :   & 01.01.1900 \vspace{0.5cm} \\
      in            &   :   & MUSTERSTADT \vspace{0.5cm} \\
      Anschrift     &   :   & MUSTERSTADT    
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\vspace{1cm}
\hrule
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \textbf{Ausbildungsbetrieb} &   :   & \textbf{MUSTERMANN AG} \vspace{0.5cm} \\    
      Anschrift                 &   :   & MUSTERSTADT \vspace{0.5cm} \\
      betrieblicher Ausbilder   &   :   & MAIK MUSTERMANN \vspace{0.5cm} \\
      Ausbildungsberuf          &   :   & Fachinformatiker für Systemintegration \vspace{0.5cm} \\
      Ausbildungsdauer          &   :   & 09/2014 bis 09/2016
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{titlepage} 

\oddsidemargin-3mm 
%\evensidemargin-3mm 
\topmargin-10mm 
\textheight30cm 
\headheight5mm 
\textwidth30cm 
\headwidth183mm 
\headsep7mm 
\hoffset-7mm
\voffset-10mm


\head{1.}{5}{2006-09-25}{2006-09-29}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabularx}{183mm}{|c|p{144mm}|c|c|}\hline
    & & & \\
    Zeit & Betriebliche Tätigkeiten & Std. & Std. \\ 
    & & & \\ \hline
    \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\large \quad Montag \quad}} &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\ \hline
    \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\large \quad Dienstag \quad}} &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\ \hline
     \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\large \quad Mittwoch \quad}} &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\ \hline
     \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\large \quad Donnerstag \quad}} &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\ \hline
     \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\large \quad Freitag \quad}} &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\
     &  & & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table} 

\foot



\end{document}
```

The problem is that my "footer" is on the first page, but my table is on the second page. I tried to make the table smaller, but it won't help and I do need such a "big" table for my report.

How can I get my table above my footer?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. The code you gave us is not compilable. Please try to reduce it to a minimum and make it complete so that we can run it on our machines.

Comment: It will help if you don't use the `table` environment: just use `tabular`. But, if the table is too big for the page, you either have to make the table smaller or the page bigger. (If it is close, you can lie about its size but that's an option of last resort.)

Comment: Changing the page dimensions manually is a bad idea if you are using `geometry`. Use `geometry`'s commands to do this if necessary.

Comment: Try the \longtable package. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23298/help-on-converting-table-to-longtable

Comment: Thanks to cfr, the tip to set the page-dimensions with geometry worked!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create a minimal example to illustrate the idea based on your code but since the code seems to want to do very odd things and I don't know the desiderata, I failed horribly.

So, here are just some notes:

- Don't set page dimensions manually if using `geometry`. Use `\usepackage[<options>]{geometry}` or `\geometry{<options>}` in the preamble. In the document, you can alter this with `\newgeometry{<options>}`.
- Read the console output to figure out the required head height. `fancyhdr` tells you this. In your case, you need to pass geometry `headheight=29pt` as the minimum required to ensure consistent page layout.
- `tabularx` requires that *at least one column be of type `X`*. If you don't want this, use `tabular` instead.
- If you say `\newcommand\fancycommand[5]{...}` then `\fancycommand` *needs* 5 arguments and will cause a fatal error otherwise. If you aren't doing anything with the arguments anyway (as here), just say `\newcommand\fancycommand{...}`.
- Note that TeX cannot meaningfully use a text height and width which exceeds that of the paper. It makes no sense to ask for a 300x300mm text block if you are using A4.