# Help with coverting tabularx into longtable

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

I am new to LaTeX. I am trying to change a tablarx into a longtable and to keep the caption below the table. I tried many answers such as this [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23299/106883) but none seem to work to me.

```
%\linebreak
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage[utf8x,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline          
    Chevauche- ment &   Méthode de détection & Paramètre & Nombre de communautés & Nombre moyen de communautés par snapshot & Taille moyenne de communautés \\

    \hline          
    \multirow{4}{*}{$0\%$} & \multirow{3}{*}{CPM} & 3 & 14066 & 275.80 & 4.60\\
    \cline{3-6}
    & & 5 & 99 & 3.67 & 5.77 \\
    \cline{3-6}
    & & 7 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & SLPA & & 20393 & 755.30 & 12.25 \\
    \hline 

    \multirow{4}{*}{$20\%$} & \multirow{3}{*}{CPM} & 3 & 15176 & 459.88 & 4.62\\
    \cline{3-6}
    & & 5 & 133 & 4.03 & 5.82 \\
    \cline{3-6}
    & & 7 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & SLPA & & 24152& 731.88 & 12.51 \\
    \hline 

    \multirow{4}{*}{$50\%$} & \multirow{3}{*}{CPM}  & 3 & 24698 & 466 & 4.59\\
    \cline{3-6}
    & & 5 & 200 & 3.77 & 5.85 \\
    \cline{3-6}
    & & 7 & 2 & 0.04 & 7.5 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & SLPA & & 39661 & 748.32 & 12.44 \\
    \hline 
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{Caractéristiques des communautés de Facebook en variant le taux de chevauchement de snapshots et la méthode de détection des communautés}
    \label{facebook-Detect-test-label}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Any help on how I can convert this table into `longtable`?

### Edit my Manuel Kuehner

I changed the code to be more minimal. Most of the packages had no relation to the question.

```
\documentclass{report}

% Ltxtable pro­vides the func­tion­al­ity of longtable and tab­u­larx to­gether in­side a longtable en­vi­ron­ment.
\usepackage{ltxtable}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline          
    Chevauche- ment &   Méthode de détection & Paramètre & Nombre de communautés & Nombre moyen de communautés par snapshot & Taille moyenne de communautés \\

    \hline          
    \multirow{4}{*}{$0\%$} & \multirow{3}{*}{CPM} & 3 & 14066 & 275.80 & 4.60\\
    \cline{3-6}
    & & 5 & 99 & 3.67 & 5.77 \\
    \cline{3-6}
    & & 7 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & SLPA & & 20393 & 755.30 & 12.25 \\
    \hline 

    \multirow{4}{*}{$20\%$} & \multirow{3}{*}{CPM} & 3 & 15176 & 459.88 & 4.62\\
    \cline{3-6}
    & & 5 & 133 & 4.03 & 5.82 \\
    \cline{3-6}
    & & 7 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & SLPA & & 24152& 731.88 & 12.51 \\
    \hline 

    \multirow{4}{*}{$50\%$} & \multirow{3}{*}{CPM}  & 3 & 24698 & 466 & 4.59\\
    \cline{3-6}
    & & 5 & 200 & 3.77 & 5.85 \\
    \cline{3-6}
    & & 7 & 2 & 0.04 & 7.5 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & SLPA & & 39661 & 748.32 & 12.44 \\
    \hline 
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{Caractéristiques des communautés de Facebook en variant le taux de chevauchement de snapshots et la méthode de détection des communautés}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the direct translation would be as below, although I would never use `p` or `X` columns for tables of data.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage[utf8x,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}


\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{Y}{p{\dimexpr(\textwidth-7\arrayrulewidth-12\tabcolsep)/6\relax}}
\begin{longtable}{|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|}
    \caption{Caractéristiques des communautés de Facebook en variant le taux de chevauchement de snapshots et la méthode de détection des communautés}
    \label{facebook-Detect-test-label}\\
\hline          
    Chevauche- ment &   Méthode de détection & Paramètre & Nombre de communautés & Nombre moyen de communautés par snapshot & Taille moyenne de communautés \\

    \hline          
    \multirow{4}{*}{$0\%$} & \multirow{3}{*}{CPM} & 3 & 14066 & 275.80 & 4.60\\
    \cline{3-6}
    & & 5 & 99 & 3.67 & 5.77 \\
    \cline{3-6}
    & & 7 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & SLPA & & 20393 & 755.30 & 12.25 \\
    \hline 

    \multirow{4}{*}{$20\%$} & \multirow{3}{*}{CPM} & 3 & 15176 & 459.88 & 4.62\\
    \cline{3-6}
    & & 5 & 133 & 4.03 & 5.82 \\
    \cline{3-6}
    & & 7 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & SLPA & & 24152& 731.88 & 12.51 \\
    \hline 

    \multirow{4}{*}{$50\%$} & \multirow{3}{*}{CPM}  & 3 & 24698 & 466 & 4.59\\
    \cline{3-6}
    & & 5 & 200 & 3.77 & 5.85 \\
    \cline{3-6}
    & & 7 & 2 & 0.04 & 7.5 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & SLPA & & 39661 & 748.32 & 12.44 \\
    \hline 



\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. It was specified in the question that the caption is needed to be below the table.

Comment: @Joker00 well no matter, the `\caption` just goes wherever you put it so you can change that easily enough.