# Split table of abbreviations over multiple pages

Tags: tables

I wounder if you could help me to solve the long table problem in my list of abbreviation, I want to separate my table in 2 or 3 pages.
My Code is:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\huge\sc\centering}
\chaptertitlefont{\centering}
\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols}
\chapter*{List of Abbreviation}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Abbreviation} & \textbf{Meaning}                                  \\ \hline
DG                    & Distributed Generation                            \\ \hline
EPRI                  & Electric Power Research Institute                 \\ \hline
CIGRE                 & International Councilon Large Electric Systems    \\ \hline
IEEE                  & Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers \\ \hline
IEA                   & International Energy Agency                       \\ \hline
DER                   & Distributed Energy Resource                       \\ \hline
BES                   & Bulk Electric System                              \\ \hline
MV                    & Medium Voltage                                    \\ \hline
LV                    & Low Voltage                                       \\ \hline
PV                    & Photovoltaic Systems                              \\ \hline
PVPP                  & PV Power Plants                                   \\ \hline
AC                    & Alternating Current                               \\ \hline
DC                    & Direct Current                                    \\ \hline
CT                    & Current Transforms                                \\ \hline
VT                    & Valtage Transforms                                \\ \hline
OR                    & Overcurrent Relay                                 \\ \hline
CTI                   & Coordinating Time Interval                        \\ \hline
MM                    & Minimum Meting                                    \\ \hline
TC                    & Total Clearing                                    \\ \hline
CSP                   & Concentrating Solar Power                         \\ \hline
SWH                   & Solar Water Heating                               \\ \hline
PCC                   & Point of Common Coupling                          \\ \hline
CB                    & Circuit Breaker                                   \\ \hline
DN                    & Distribution Network                              \\ \hline
CCT                   & Critical Clearing Time                            \\ \hline
DNOs                  & Distribution Network Operators                    \\ \hline
EPS                   & Electric Power Systems                            \\ \hline
FRT                   & Fault Ride Through                                \\ \hline
CSU                   & Current Sensing Unit                              \\ \hline
GTO                   & Gate Turn off Thyristor                           \\ \hline
OPF                   & Optimal Power Flow                                \\ \hline
PSO                   & Particle Swarm Optimization                       \\ \hline
GA                    & Genetic Algorithm                                 \\ \hline
RTU                   & Remote Thermal Units                              \\ \hline
RNC                   & Ring Network Cabinet                              \\ \hline
MS                    & Master Station                                    \\ \hline
FFT                   & Fast Fourier Transform                            \\ \hline
THD                   & Total Harmonic Distortion                         \\ \hline
FCL                   & Fault Current Limiters                            \\ \hline
SMES                  & Superconducting Magnetic Energy Storage           \\ \hline
IEDs                  & Intelligent Electronic Devices                    \\ \hline
SCADA                 & Supervisory Control and Data Acquisition          \\ \hline
LBPC                  & Local Backup Protection Center                    \\ \hline
SBPC                  & System Backup Protection Center                   \\ \hline
WPT                   & Wavelet Packet Transform                          \\ \hline
LG                    & Line-Ground                                       \\ \hline
LLG                   & Line- Line-Ground                                 \\ \hline
LLLG                  & Three Phase Fault                                 \\ \hline
MDL                   & Minimum Description Length                        \\ \hline
MMF                   & Mathematical Morphology Filters                   \\ \hline
CMS                   & Current Multiplier setting                        \\ \hline
TMS                   & Time Multiplier Setting                           \\ \hline
IP                    & Primary Relay                                     \\ \hline
IB                    & Backup Relay                                      \\ \hline
ETAP                  & Electrical Transient Analysis Program             \\ \hline
PS                    & Plug Setting                                      \\ \hline
CTR                   & Current Transformer Ratio                         \\ \hline
APS                   & Adaptive Protection Scheme                        \\ \hline
SCC                   & Short Circuit Current                             \\ \hline
PMS                   & Plug Multiplying Setting                          \\ \hline
FRB                   & Fuzzy Rule Base                                   \\ \hline
DOCRs                 & Directional Over-Current Relays                   \\ \hline
MINLP                 & Mixed Integer Non-linear Programming              \\ \hline
MILP                  & Mixed Integer Linear Programming                  \\ \hline
LP                    & Linear Programming                                \\ \hline
MOPSO                 & Multi-Objective Particle Swarm Optimization       \\ \hline
FDMT                  & Fuzzy Decision Making Tool                        \\ \hline
OFs                   & Objective Functions                               \\ \hline
DT                    & Duration Time                                     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would packages like nomenclature or acronym be a solution?

Comment: Have you tried using the `longtable` LaTeX package (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23298/help-on-converting-table-to-longtable)), which allows breaking tables over multiple pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `longtable`. I suggest left alignment and no rules, to ease reading. Also, since it's already declared to be a list of abbreviations, it is not necessary to have a table heading.

When the list is complete, it's better to sort it, in order to help readers in finding the abbreviations.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{sectsty}

\chapterfont{\huge\normalfont\scshape\centering}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{List of Abbreviations}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}

\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}

\begin{longtable}{@{}ll@{}}
DG                    & Distributed Generation                            \\
EPRI                  & Electric Power Research Institute                 \\
CIGRE                 & International Councilon Large Electric Systems    \\
IEEE                  & Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers \\
IEA                   & International Energy Agency                       \\
DER                   & Distributed Energy Resource                       \\
BES                   & Bulk Electric System                              \\
MV                    & Medium Voltage                                    \\
LV                    & Low Voltage                                       \\
PV                    & Photovoltaic Systems                              \\
PVPP                  & PV Power Plants                                   \\
AC                    & Alternating Current                               \\
DC                    & Direct Current                                    \\
CT                    & Current Transforms                                \\
VT                    & Valtage Transforms                                \\
OR                    & Overcurrent Relay                                 \\
CTI                   & Coordinating Time Interval                        \\
MM                    & Minimum Meting                                    \\
TC                    & Total Clearing                                    \\
CSP                   & Concentrating Solar Power                         \\
SWH                   & Solar Water Heating                               \\
PCC                   & Point of Common Coupling                          \\
CB                    & Circuit Breaker                                   \\
DN                    & Distribution Network                              \\
CCT                   & Critical Clearing Time                            \\
DNOs                  & Distribution Network Operators                    \\
EPS                   & Electric Power Systems                            \\
FRT                   & Fault Ride Through                                \\
CSU                   & Current Sensing Unit                              \\
GTO                   & Gate Turn off Thyristor                           \\
OPF                   & Optimal Power Flow                                \\
PSO                   & Particle Swarm Optimization                       \\
GA                    & Genetic Algorithm                                 \\
RTU                   & Remote Thermal Units                              \\
RNC                   & Ring Network Cabinet                              \\
MS                    & Master Station                                    \\
FFT                   & Fast Fourier Transform                            \\
THD                   & Total Harmonic Distortion                         \\
FCL                   & Fault Current Limiters                            \\
SMES                  & Superconducting Magnetic Energy Storage           \\
IEDs                  & Intelligent Electronic Devices                    \\
SCADA                 & Supervisory Control and Data Acquisition          \\
LBPC                  & Local Backup Protection Center                    \\
SBPC                  & System Backup Protection Center                   \\
WPT                   & Wavelet Packet Transform                          \\
LG                    & Line-Ground                                       \\
LLG                   & Line- Line-Ground                                 \\
LLLG                  & Three Phase Fault                                 \\
MDL                   & Minimum Description Length                        \\
MMF                   & Mathematical Morphology Filters                   \\
CMS                   & Current Multiplier setting                        \\
TMS                   & Time Multiplier Setting                           \\
IP                    & Primary Relay                                     \\
IB                    & Backup Relay                                      \\
ETAP                  & Electrical Transient Analysis Program             \\
PS                    & Plug Setting                                      \\
CTR                   & Current Transformer Ratio                         \\
APS                   & Adaptive Protection Scheme                        \\
SCC                   & Short Circuit Current                             \\
PMS                   & Plug Multiplying Setting                          \\
FRB                   & Fuzzy Rule Base                                   \\
DOCRs                 & Directional Over-Current Relays                   \\
MINLP                 & Mixed Integer Non-linear Programming              \\
MILP                  & Mixed Integer Linear Programming                  \\
LP                    & Linear Programming                                \\
MOPSO                 & Multi-Objective Particle Swarm Optimization       \\
FDMT                  & Fuzzy Decision Making Tool                        \\
OFs                   & Objective Functions                               \\
DT                    & Duration Time                                     \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Note that I used `\normalfont\scshape`, as `\sc` has been deprecated for more than 20 years.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @egreg for you helping, Could you explain what's the benefit of `\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}` please? thanks for your attention