# How to use longtable in latex?

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a really long table and it does not fit the page. So, I want it to span on several pages. When I google about my issue, I came accross `longtable`. However, it seems like `longtable` do not support `tabular` format. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable*}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{My data}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.8cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{1.6cm}|p{2.2cm}|P{0.8cm}|p{2.6cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Year} & \textbf{ID} & \textbf{Address} & \textbf{Salary} & \textbf{Skills} & \textbf{Qualifications} \\
\hline
Some text & some text & some text & 5 & some text & Som text
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table3}
\end{longtable*}
\end{document}
```

Please let me know if any further details are needed. :)

**EDIT**

I did not just post the question without looking at any materials or other questions. I also tried the solution in [How to convert table to longtable being able to break across pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23298/how-to-convert-table-to-longtable-being-able-to-break-across-pages). However, that did not work either. That is why I posted the question.

Comment: The column specification goes after `\begin{longtable}` and you don't use a `\begin{tabular}` inside it. You'll find some examples of using `longtable` in [its manual](http://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf) and lots more [here in this site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/longtable).

Comment: type `texdoc longtable` and the manual has many examples or look at the [tag:longtable] tag on this site for thousands more examples.

Comment: There is no `longtable*` environment.

Comment: On a different note, *never* use vertical separators in tables.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have several issues in your given code, for example command `\label` has to follow `\caption` ...

You should not use verticals lines and instead of `\hline` have better a look to package `booktabs` (type `texdoc booktabs` on your terminal/console) ...

How you get the title back for the second page I left over for you. Please read the manual of `longtable` (type `texdoc longtable` on your terminal/console) ...

With the following corrected code

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{showframe} % to visualize writing area and margins ...
\usepackage{blindtext} % to generate dummy text


\begin{document}

\Blindtext
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\begin{longtable}{|p{2.8cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{1.6cm}|p{2.2cm}|P{0.8cm}|p{2.6cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
\caption{My data}
\label{tab:table3}\\
\hline
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Year} & \textbf{ID} & \textbf{Address} & \textbf{Salary} & \textbf{Skills} & \textbf{Qualifications} \\
\hline
Some text & some text & some text & 5 & some text & Som text &\\
\hline
Some text & some text & some text & 5 & some text & Som text &\\
\hline
Some text & some text & some text & 5 & some text & Som text &\\
\hline
Some text & some text & some text & 5 & some text & Som text &\\
\hline
Some text & some text & some text & 5 & some text & Som text &\\
\hline
Some text & some text & some text & 5 & some text & Som text &\\
\hline
Some text & some text & some text & 5 & some text & Som text &\\
\hline
Some text & some text & some text & 5 & some text & Som text &\\
\hline
Some text & some text & some text & 5 & some text & Som text &\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot :) However, this still gives me an error in `\begin{longtable}{|p{2.8cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{1.6cm}|p{2.2cm}|P{0.8cm}|p{2.6cm}|p{2.5cm}|}`. It says that `longtable not in 1-column mode`. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Emi Well, I think you do not want to hear that: no, `longtable` can not run in a two column layout (see manual).  In my code I do not get that error, so in your origin you used something you did not show in your MWE :-( Try to add `\onecolumn` before the long table and add `\twocolum` after.

Comment: @EmJ someone posted that question, see the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161455/164146)

Comment: one of OP main question is about the use of `tabular`, but your answer does not explicitly mention it should indeed be removed!?

Comment: Thank you for this code - it helped me to deal with a loooong table. However, I struggle with the lines, they are nice on the right side of the table but on the left side they dont go all the way up. Is there a way I can change this?