# Page break in a tablestyles long table

Tags: tables, formatting, longtable

## Context

I'm using the [tablestyles](https://ctan.org/pkg/tablestyles) package to build nice tables for rendering database schema and tables.

## Issue

But I'm not able to figure out a way to nicely break a table when it is longer than an A4 page (fig.1).
There is no mention of [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) in the [tablestyles documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tablestyles/tablestyles.pdf), but it relies on the [tabular](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabular_environment) environment or the [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package, it this helps.

[image: Screenshot]
*Fig.1: Table doesn't break at the end of the page. Rendered using [TexMaker](https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) `5.0.2` on Ubuntu `18.04`.*

## MRE

Here is a piece of code, feel free to duplicate one row N-time with a great N value (e.g. 100):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  left=2cm,
  right=1.6cm,
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  footskip=30pt
}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tablestyles}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{makecell} % buggy

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{table}[H]
\tablestyle[sansboldbw]
\centering
\caption{The long table.}
%\begin{tabular}{*{4}{p{0.24\textwidth}}} % nope, this doesn't adapt to the columns' content
%\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\stretch{1}}}*{4}{l}@{}} % buggy
% You can replace \begin{tabular} by \begin{longtable}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.29\linewidth}p{0.24\linewidth}p{0.22\linewidth}p{0.18\linewidth}}

\theadstart
\thead Column\_category &  
\thead Type & 
\thead Information1 & 
\thead Information2 \\
\tbody

Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\

\tend
% You can replace \end{tabular} by \end{longtable}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Replacing `\begin{tabular}` and `\end{tabular}` by `\begin{longtable}` and `\end{longtable}` has no effect.

## Helpful threads

[Which tabular packages do which tasks and which packages conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12672/which-tabular-packages-do-which-tasks-and-which-packages-conflict)
[How to convert table to longtable being able to break across pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23298/how-to-convert-table-to-longtable-being-able-to-break-across-pages)

Comment: Since you mentioned replacing `tabular` with `longtable`: A `longtable` environment can not be used inside of a `table` environment sinc `table` does not suppprt page breaks.

Comment: Does this mean you cannot have a long table with a caption?

Comment: Sure you can have a `longtable`with a `\caption`. In that case, place the `\caption` after `\begin{longtable}` and add a `\\ ` after the `\caption`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should point you in the right direction. I have corrected the `longtable` syntax and asked to show the caption on the first page only while the column headers will be repeated on all following pages. I have also adjusted the column widths since your table was wider than the textwidth. You might have to do some more adjustments and probably want to change to a reggedright alignment instead of justified text in the individual columns.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  left=2cm,
  right=1.6cm,
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  footskip=30pt
}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tablestyles}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{makecell} % buggy
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{showframe}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\begin{table}[H]
\tablestyle[sansboldbw]
%\centering
%\caption{The long table.}
%\begin{tabular}{*{4}{p{0.24\textwidth}}} % nope, this doesn't adapt to the columns' content
%\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\stretch{1}}}*{4}{l}@{}} % buggy
% You can replace \begin{tabular} by \begin{longtable}
\begin{longtable}{p{0.31\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}p{0.26\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}p{0.22\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}p{0.21\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\rowcolor{white}\caption{The long table.}\label{key}\\
\theadstart
\thead Column\_category &  
\thead Type & 
\thead Information1 & 
\thead Information2 \\
\endfirsthead
\theadstart
\thead Column\_category &  
\thead Type & 
\thead Information1 & 
\thead Information2 \\
\endhead
\tbody

Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\
Quisque laoreet ultricies fringilla. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & Pellentesque accumsan & Morbi nec est lacus \\

\tend
% You can replace \end{tabular} by \end{longtable}
\end{longtable}
%\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for the tricks.